# library on maven2 central repository but not on mvnrepository.com

Tags: java, maven

I've create a library and followed all the step to upload it to maven.

When I do a maven search, I can find it on search.maven.org

I am unable to find it on mvnrepository.com

It is also on maven central repository:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/github/jlarrieux/

Is there a delay?

Please help

Comment: AFAIK, mvnrepository.com is not an "official" maven resource. It's a 3rd party operation.

Comment: mvnrepository is not Maven Central as already mentioned *only* search index....

Comment: My understanding was searching on mvn should show same result as maven central. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

There's a delay on indexing new artifacts.
As you can see in http://mvnrepository.com/repos/central, the Central Repository have  1,974,591 indexed jars, but if you visit the same page on [Google Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NkOcsp3HxhwJ:https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central), cached a couple of hours ago, it says that it has 1,971,503 indexed jars.

So, just a little bit of patience :)